# Cannot read property 'setDefaults' of undefined

Tags: wordpress

Cannot read property 'setDefaults' of undefined for non login user in wordpress and  my css and js not working due to above problem.

How to solve this problem.

please tell about the solution.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem will increase your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: you can get the error from the code as you use the css and js in the code. Can you share with us your code?